# How do I change my spring security to use jdbc instead of ldap?

Tags: java, spring, security, jdbc, ldap

I completed the Spring guide "Authenticating a User with LDAP" and am attempting to rip out the LDAP part and replace it with a connection to a MySQL database."

I have no idea how to inject this DataSource. I'm currently getting a red cross in Eclipse saying "dataSource cannot be resolved or is not a field".

I've got a database set up and running on my local machine, but am unsure where to tell Spring the credentials for connecting.

1. What do I need to add to inject this DataSource Properly?
2. How do I tell Spring what credentials to use to connect to my database?
3. Am I missing any other crucial steps to getting my authentication working?

   ```
   package hello;

   import javax.inject.Inject;
   import javax.sql.DataSource;

   import hello.UserAccountDAO;

   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvcSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       @Inject
       DataSource dataSource;

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
       }

       @Configuration
       protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

           @Override
           public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

               // auth
               // .ldapAuthentication()
               // .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
               // .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
               // .contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");

               auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource)
                       .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT Username, Password, Enabled FROM User WHERE Username = ?")
                       .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT Username, Permission FROM UserPermission WHERE Username = ?")
                       .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you have an xml configuration file where you have datasource listed as a bean?

Comment: I do not. Is it possible to do this with annotations?

Comment: Ok then how is your data source currently configured for it to be Injected to this class?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to do that

Comment: HAve a look at the example here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/. Its using mysql and `javax.sql.dataDource`